# Array index start random in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I need to visit items in array starting to index random.

My code

```
from random import randrange

fruits = ['banana', 'apple',  'mango']

index = randrange(len(fruits))
for index in fruits[index:]:
     print index
```

It is possible when index is 1 or 2 after to print start again in index 0 or 1 in that loop for.

Example:

Randon index is 1 print = 'apple' 'mango' 'banana'

Randon index is 2 print = 'mango' 'apple' 'banana'

Comment: First, you're overloading the word `index`, which is going to screw you up. Second, you should be able to use the `%` modulus operator to get that working, I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
from random import randrange

fruits = ['banana', 'apple',  'mango']
randomOffset = randrange(0,len(fruits))
for i in range(len(fruits)):       
   print fruits[i - randomOffset]
```

You could use an index of `(i + randomOffset) % len(fruits)` to be more clear, but giving a negative index in python works by starting from the back of the array and counting backwards. So in effect, you'd be just starting somewhere randomly in the array - set by `randomOffset`, and then takign al lthe subsequent items.

Comment: Negative indices, I like it.

Comment: @JohniDouglasMarangon you can check it as correct if you want!

Answer (score 2):

A deque is built for this operation: [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Instead of using `fruits[index:]`, you could create a deque and rotate it:

```
from collections import deque

fruit_deque = deque(fruits)
fruit_deque.rotate(-index)

for fruit in fruit_deque:
    print fruit
```

Another option is [cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

fruit_cycle = cycle(fruits)
fruit_slice = islice(fruit_cycle, index, index + len(fruits))

for fruit in fruit_slice:
    print fruit
```

You could wrap around more than once with this method, by replacing `len(fruits)` with any number (or use `islice(fruit_cycle, index, None)` to cycle indefinitely).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're just trying to visit the list in random order (since your two sample outputs aren't both rotations of the original list).

In that case, may I suggest `random.shuffle`?

```
import random
randlist = fruits[:]
random.shuffle(randlist)
for i in randlist:
    print i
```

This prints the list in a random order.

Comment: The first example is a rotation

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid a for loop and splice up to the `index` then reverse the elements greater than the `index`

```
>>> fruits = ['banana', 'apple',  'mango']
>>> index = 0
>>> fruits[index:] + fruits[:index][::-1]
['banana', 'apple', 'mango']
>>> index = 1
>>> fruits[index:] + fruits[:index][::-1]
['apple', 'mango', 'banana']
>>> index = 2
>>> fruits[index:] + fruits[:index][::-1]
['mango', 'apple', 'banana']
```